Free earlier Anaconda Navigator versions system requirements
Does anyone please know where I can find the system requirements of earlier Anaconda Navigator versions ? I am looking for the latest one compatible with 3 gb RAM, or 6 gb if I upgrade, or perhaps even more but I would have to see for that (my OS is Windows 10 64bits compatible). Thanks in advance !
I have already looked around on Anaconda website, as well as other website offering downloads, but failed to find.
Thanks in advance !

For information (and being aware that this has not raised great interest, sorry for this), I have installed version 202012 64 bit, and with 4 GB RAM associated with a recent SSD drive, it works fine.

Moderator, as long as I am concerned, you can now close the thread. Thanks
